# Bash Script - How can I get the size of directories in .txt file and save them into other file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, du

I started a few weeks with Linux bash programming, but I'm struggling with a problem: How can I get the size of multiple directories (path saved on a .txt file) and then, write into another file, the directory path, followed by size and the total size occupied by that directories.
I already tried this, but I'm not sure:

```
totsize=0
while read -r diretory; do
   size=$(du -ch "$directory")
   echo "$diretory size: $size" > "$homedir/$filename2"
   $totsize += $(du -c "$homedir/$diretorio")
done < "$homedir/diretories.txt"
sudo echo "total size: $totsize" >> "$homedir/$filename2"
```

Thanks in advance (and sorry for bad english)

Comment: I slightly improved my answer, please review. Thank you !

Comment: Do _not_ use `sudo` to echo stuff into your $HOME!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` combined with `du` and redirect to file with `>`

```
sudo find /path/to/topDir -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec du -sh {} \;  > output.txt
```

Example:

```
xieerqi:$ sudo find Desktop -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec du -sh {} \; > outputFile1.txt                                                            
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

xieerqi:$ cat outputFile1.txt                                                                                                                    
2.7G    Desktop
69M Desktop/linux-kernel-4.1.0
1.1M    Desktop/DOCS
6.8M    Desktop/The comments that became a reporter’s death sentence | New York Post_files
4.0K    Desktop/newdir
6.7M    Desktop/IMAGES
12M Desktop/TIRES
504K    Desktop/MSU-TEMPLATES
341M    Desktop/PDFS
19M Desktop/java
```

To have this command give disk usage for specific directories from list , what you can do is combine cat and xargs with the command above. For example,

```
 cat dirList.txt | xargs -I dir sudo find dir -maxdepth 0 -type d  -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Some directories of which you're not an owner require `sudo` access to list their disk usage, hence combine that with `sudo sh -c`. Let me demonstrate,

```
xieerqi:$ sudo sh -c "cat dirList.txt | xargs -I dir find dir -maxdepth 0 -type d  -exec du -sh {} \+"                                           
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
2.7G    /home/xieerqi/Desktop
11M /bin
5.5G    /usr

xieerqi:$ cat dirList.txt                                                                                                                        
/home/xieerqi/Desktop
/bin
/usr
```

Comment: @guntbert yes, literally had to post in last minute before taking a quiz in class .Thank you for the edit. I'll fix it up a bit later

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with files or directories by their name, I highly recommend to deal with them separated by the nullbyte character, not by a newline. Because officially a filename **can** contain a newline. So you should not make a list of the directories separated by a newline.

Anyway, when you have this list you can just use this:

```
du -sch --files0-from=dirs.txt
```

- `-s` is like `-d0` and will only summarize a total for each argument.
- `-c` calculates a grand total.
- `-h` does that all in human readable format.
- `--files0-from=dirs.txt` reads the filenames/directorynames from the given file terminated by nullbyte.

---

With your list, it whould look like (but with the pitfall of filenames with newlines in it):

```
tr '\n' '\0' <dirs.txt | du -sch --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get size of directories with `du` command like this:

```
du -h -d 1 "path to parent directory"
```

**-d:** the depth of subdirectories